# Trouble connecting email to activity

Tags: civimail

I have a fresh install of civicrm 5.16.3 running on drupal 7. I am having trouble with the mail processor. I've read many pages trying to diagnose the issue and still no luck.

This is what I am getting from civi log, I changed username and server information.

I have tried connecting to a server that I can sucessfully connect to using another computer with civi installed, but no luck on this configuation.

---

```
Aug 27 12:41:22  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [message] => Could not connect to MailStore for username@server <p>Error message: <pre>An error occured while sending or receiving mail. Failed to connect to the server: server:993.</pre><p>
    [code] => 
)


Aug 27 12:41:22  [info] $backTrace = #0 /var/www/html/drupal-7.66/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(343): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /var/www/html/drupal-7.66/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Mail/EmailProcessor.php(175): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("Could not connect to MailStore for username@server...")
#2 /var/www/html/drupal-7.66/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Mail/EmailProcessor.php(103): CRM_Utils_Mail_EmailProcessor::_process(FALSE, Object(CRM_Core_DAO_MailSettings), TRUE)
#3 /var/www/html/drupal-7.66/modules/civicrm/api/v3/Job.php(438): CRM_Utils_Mail_EmailProcessor::processActivities()
#4 /var/www/html/drupal-7.66/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(101): civicrm_api3_job_fetch_activities((Array:1))
#5 /var/www/html/drupal-7.66/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(168): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke((Array:9))
#6 /var/www/html/drupal-7.66/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(99): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest((Array:9))
#7 /var/www/html/drupal-7.66/modules/civicrm/api/api.php(23): Civi\API\Kernel->runSafe("job", "fetch_activities", (Array:1), NULL)
#8 /var/www/html/drupal-7.66/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/JobManager.php(149): civicrm_api("job", "fetch_activities", (Array:1))
#9 /var/www/html/drupal-7.66/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/JobManager.php(116): CRM_Core_JobManager->executeJob(Object(CRM_Core_ScheduledJob))
#10 /var/www/html/drupal-7.66/modules/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/Job.php(173): CRM_Core_JobManager->executeJobById("3")
#11 /var/www/html/drupal-7.66/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php(160): CRM_Admin_Page_Job->browse(NULL, NULL)
#12 /var/www/html/drupal-7.66/modules/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/Job.php(156): CRM_Core_Page_Basic->run()
#13 /var/www/html/drupal-7.66/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(311): CRM_Admin_Page_Job->run((Array:3), NULL)
#14 /var/www/html/drupal-7.66/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(85): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:16))
#15 /var/www/html/drupal-7.66/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#16 /var/www/html/drupal-7.66/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(456): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#17 /var/www/html/drupal-7.66/includes/menu.inc(527): civicrm_invoke("admin", "job")
#18 /var/www/html/drupal-7.66/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#19 {main}
```

Comment: Does that server allow port 993 outbound?

Comment: I just tried to telnet to that port and I connected successfully

Comment: On the admin screen for the mail account in civi do you have Use SSL checked?

Comment: I do have ssl checked on the mail account

Comment: I'm out of ideas at the moment since you said you can connect to the same mailserver from another civi install (or was that test a DIFFERENT mail server?)

Comment: I can connect to the same server using a different civi install, issue seems to be something to do with the civi install and not the mail server

Comment: So this civi install doesn't seem to connect to any mail server

Comment: All I can think of is to add debugging output to CRM_Mailing_MailStore_Imap::__construct() and try to see exactly which line it fails on.

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to do that but I'm not sure how. I turned debugging on in the debugging section

Comment: I just meant edit the file CRM/Mailing/MailStore/Imap.php and add `echo 'this is step X';` or `CRM_Core_Error::debug_log_message('this is step X');` statements sprinkled in __contruct(). Then where it stops outputting your messages is where it fails.

Comment: Also you said you tried telnet but it might be useful to also try `openssl s_client -connect server:993` just to check that too.

Comment: Looks like the openssl connection works without a problem

Comment: In the message you get does it literally say "server:993" or is that your redacted version?  What mail accounts do you have defined? (at Administer > CiviMail > Mail Accounts)?

Comment: That is my redacted version. It says fails to connect to mail.myserver.org:993 I only have the one account defined right now

Comment: So I found where the script fails. In CRM/Mailing/Mailstore.php, I don't get 'this is step X' after the line     $this->_transport = new ezcMailImapTransport($host, NULL, $options);, so I presume the problem is occuring at this point in the code

Comment: I tried using an older file of imap_transport.php from civicrm version 4.7.30 where my setup is working, but still no go. I'm wondering if the php version might be the issue

Comment: I've gone farther down into the .php, found that vendor/zetacomponents/mail/src/transports/transport_connection.php , $this->connection = @stream_socket_client( "ssl://{$server}:{$port}" there is not an active connection, because if ( is_resource( $this->connection ) ) is skipped and it goes to throw new ezcMailTransportException( "Failed to connect to the server: {$server}:{$port}." );
not sure how to troubleshoot at this point, any advice would be appreciated

Comment: So to add to this, because I suspect that this is an ssl problem, when I do openssl s_client -connect server:993, I do connect, but I get this warning: Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate).

Comment: So I fixed my problem, once I fixed my certificate problem, civimail email to activity started working again. Thanks to the advice on this page, I was able to diagnose the problem more quickly, between the openssl lead and the idea of printing output in php to isolate where the script was failing.